# Integrating ScanAPI 10.3.90 to iPad iOS 10.2 with 7Xi scanner

Tags: socketmobile

I am trying to connect 7Xi scanner to SingleEntry project.

For a very first time I just started scanner and connect to Bluetooth so I guess it was HID connection. I refer Readme file from SingleEntry project.

So I tried to setup scanner in iOS mode by

1. I reset the scanner pairing by pressing Scanner’s large button + on/off button.
2. I have generated

> ```
> #FNC IOS ACCEPTOR 000000000000#
> ```

barcode and scanned it.

Now, how would I get to know that scanner is setup for iOS mode and not for HID ? As I am seeing same name in Bluetooth manager of my pc and iPad.

[image]

If I pair and Run the SingleEntry project nothing is happening. No delegates being called.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. In `Readme` file its mentioned :

> For the 7Xi/Qi: #FNC IOS ACCEPTOR 000000000000#
>
> For all others (1D scanners and 8Qi): #FNB00F40002#

For me `#FNB00F40002#` worked to change scanner to iOS mode from HID mode.

Now its working. Also it will not work with Simulator.